# Multi-component application build with Excelsior-jet maven plugin

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to do multi-component applications with excelsior jet maven plugin?

Our normal way of building excelsior installer is to have two excelsior projects "app.prj/exe" and "dep.prj/dll". In "app.exe" there is our application code, in "dep.dll" there are third party dependencies which are not changed a lot. With this two components we can quickly build excelsior installer without having to rebuild "dep" again.

In "app.prj" we are using directive !uses, but I cannot find it in maven plugin.

Now we want to use maven excelsior jet plugin in our project, but can/how we do it as multi-component application?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the [answer](https://github.com/excelsior-oss/excelsior-jet-maven-plugin/issues/63) from the plugin's bug tracker on GitHub:

> No, the plugin does not support it yet.
>
> <...>
>
> We are working on this problem and we are going to support global compilation cache in the compiler itself (so you will not need to recompile your dependencies). Multi-component support from the plugin is possible but as far as multi-component model is used as workaround for the compilation problem, we think that we need to provide a better solution for the problem.